# How to delete a feature from a GeoJSON with Python

Tags: python, geojson

Given a GeoJSON like following:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "city": "city1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          113.5546875,
          63.704722429433225
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "city": "city2"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          56.953125,
          41.508577297439324
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I delete (or generate a new GeoJSON) the feature with the `city` property value `city2` with Python?

So far I have this, though I am a little stuck in my logical right now. Would apprecaite help or suggestions.

```
import json
city_name = "city2"
city_geojson = [city if city['properties']['city'] != city_name else '' for city in city_geojson['features']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick hack that might suit you:

```
import itertools

t = {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [{'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [113.5546875, 63.704722429433225]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'city': 'city1'}}, {'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [56.953125, 41.508577297439324]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'city': 'city2'}}]}

features = []
for k,v in itertools.groupby([x for x in t['features'] if not x['properties']['city'] == 'city2' ]):  # filter out city2
    features.append(k)
t['features'] = features

# t = {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [{'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [113.5546875, 63.704722429433225]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'city': 'city1'}}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @nickves answer I adapted my code to the following which worked for me.

```
import json
city_name = "city2"
city_geojson['features'] = [city for city in city_geojson['features'] if not city['properties']['city'] == city_name]
```

Comment: I don't think it goes any better than this

Answer (score 1):

The result of `json.loads(geojson)` is a Python dictionary. You can simply use the json module (or the [geojson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geojson/) module) and dictionaries as it was planned.

```
geojson = "{'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': [{'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [113.5546875, 63.704722429433225]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'city': 'city1'}}, {'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [56.953125, 41.508577297439324]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'city': 'city2'}}]}"
res = json.loads(geojson)
# now res is a Python dictionary with the keys 
print res.keys()
[u'type', 'features']
print len(res['features'])
2 # two features
# select only the first feature 
geojson2 = {"type": res['type'],"features":res.features[0]}
print geojson2
{'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': {"geometry": {"coordinates": [113.5546875, 63.704722429433225], "type": "Point"}, "id": null, "properties": {"city": "city1"}, "type": "Feature"}}
# convert to JSON format
json.dumps(geojson2)
'{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": {"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [113.5546875, 63.704722429433225]}, "type": "Feature", "id": null, "properties": {"city": "city1"}}}'
```

The problem was that the result  is no longer a FeatureCollection but a simple feature

```
 geojson3  = res.features[0]
 print  geojson3
{"geometry": {"coordinates": [113.5546875, 63.704722429433225], "type": "Point"}, "id": null, "properties": {"city": "city1"}, "type": "Feature"}
```

Change a value

```
 geojson3['id'] = 45
 print geojson3
 {"geometry": {"coordinates": [113.5546875, 63.704722429433225], "type": "Point"}, "id": 45, "properties": {"city": "city1"}, "type": "Feature"}
```